# Why do all these custom PlotCurveItem get highlighted?

Tags: pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am writing a chart that should plot realtime data and I would like to add a bit of mouse interactions.

The number of data to plot might grow in the future so I was trying to write something slightly generic.

I wrote some custom classes to get the curve behaviour I needed, and they work fine on their own. But whenever I try to create a `PlotItem` that contains a few of them, I don't get the correct behaviour.

For example, if I hover over a curve, it gets bigger as desired, but when I leave, it doesn't get smaller.
Also it seems to inconsistently makes all of them bigger at times.

Here is the code:

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEventLoop, QTimer, QThread, pyqtSignal

import numpy as np


class DataThread(QThread):
    """Data generation"""
    update_data = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self, parent=None, delay_ms=1000):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.delay_ms = delay_ms

    def run(self):
        self._ping()
        timer = QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(self._ping)
        timer.start(self.delay_ms)
        loop = QEventLoop()
        loop.exec_()

    def _ping(self):
        tc, cj, fault = np.random.uniform(low=10, high=12, size=3).tolist()
        self.update_data.emit([tc, cj, fault])


class HoverableCurveItem(pg.PlotCurveItem):
    """Curve that triggers hover events"""

    sigCurveHovered = QtCore.Signal(object, object)
    sigCurveNotHovered = QtCore.Signal(object, object)

    def __init__(self, hoverable=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HoverableCurveItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.hoverable = hoverable
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

    def hoverEvent(self, ev):
        if self.hoverable:
            if self.mouseShape().contains(ev.pos()):
                self.sigCurveHovered.emit(self, ev)
            else:
                self.sigCurveNotHovered.emit(self, ev)


class CustomCurveItem(pg.GraphicsObject):
    """Curve with hover events that also display data points when necessary"""

    def __init__(self, x=[], y=[], pen=pg.mkPen('w', width=2), xres=5):
        super().__init__()

        self.xres = 5

        self.curve = HoverableCurveItem(pen=pen)
        self.curve.setParentItem(self)
        self.curve.sigCurveHovered.connect(self.hovered)
        self.curve.sigCurveNotHovered.connect(self.leaveHovered)

        self.scatter_get_data = pg.ScatterPlotItem()
        self.scatter_get_data.setParentItem(self)

        self.scatter_show = pg.ScatterPlotItem()
        self.scatter_show.setParentItem(self)

        self.setData(x, y)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.curve.boundingRect()

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        self.curve.paint(p, *args)
        self.scatter_show.paint(p, *args)

    def setData(self, x, y):
        self.x = x.copy()
        self.y = y.copy()
        self.curve.setData(self.x, self.y)
        self.scatter_get_data.setData(self.x, self.y)
        self.update()

    def appendData(self, x, y):
        self.x.append(x)
        self.y.append(y)
        self.setData(self.x, self.y)

    def hovered(self, item, event):
        x = int(np.round(event.pos()[0]))
        y = self.y[int(np.round(x))]
        self.curve.setPen(pg.mkPen('w', width=15))
        self.scatter_show.setData([x], [y])
        self.scatter_show.setOpacity(1)

    def leaveHovered(self):
        self.curve.setPen(pg.mkPen('w', width=10))
        self.scatter_show.setOpacity(0)


class RealTimePlotWidget(pg.PlotItem):
    """Real time, multi-data plotting"""
    def __init__(self, datanames, xres=5, history_size=1024, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.datanames = datanames
        self.xres = xres
        self.history_size = history_size

        self._data = np.zeros((len(datanames), history_size), dtype=np.float16)
        self._curidx = 0
        self._curves = [None for _ in self.datanames]
        for i in range(len(self._curves)):
            curve = CustomCurveItem()
            self._curves[i] = curve
            self.addItem(curve)

    def appendData(self, *data):
        assert len(data) == len(self.datanames), f"{len(data)} != {len(self.datanames)}"
        self._data[:, self._curidx] = data 
        for i, (curve, y) in enumerate(zip(self._curves, data)):
            curve.appendData(self._curidx, y)

        rstart = max(0, self._curidx - self.xres)
        self.setXRange(rstart, rstart + self.xres, padding=0)

        self._curidx += 1



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        self.makeplot()
        self.data_thread = DataThread(self)
        self.data_thread.update_data.connect(lambda data: (
            self.plotitem.appendData(*data)
        ))
        self.data_thread.start()

    def makeplot(self):
        self.plotitem = RealTimePlotWidget(["tj", "cj", "fault"])
        self.view.addItem(self.plotitem)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I am totally new to PyQt (and Qt) and didn't fully get the class hierarchy so please be gentle if you see any misuse of the library but feel free to share common usage improvements.

Comment: Well, for starters, remove all painting in `paint()` which is redundant: child items paint on their own, so if `CustomCurveItem` doesn't paint something *itself*, `paint()` should do *nothing*: just add `pass`. Then, I can see the pen decreasing its size, but you're not using the original width you set in the init: the default `pen` argument given in the `__init__` has a width of 2, but in `leaveHovered` you set the width to 10.